# The right way to iterate starting from 2nd record in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.1.12 view, we would like to iterate starting from 2nd record. Here is the code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :task_templates, @project_task_template.task_templates.offset(1).each do |builder| %> 
    <p><%= render('task_templates', :f => builder) %></p> 
<% end if @project_task_template.task_templates.size > 1 %>
```

What we find out is that the first record is still showing in the view and offset(1) is not skipping the first record. What's the right way to iterate starting from 2nd record in Rails (without checking the order of the record)?

Comment: You don't need to use `each` with [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

Comment: You are right. No need for .each. Actually each disables offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the object `@project_task_template.task_templates` is an Array instead of Query object. You can't chain `offset` on the array.

It's possible to solve this at view but I recommend to put such logic in model scope

```
class ProjectTaskTemplates < ActiveRecords::Base
  default_scope offset(1)
  # or any other scope if you don't want to put it as default
end
```

Or put it in controller but not View. Your view should be dumb to use instance from controller directly.

```
class ProjectTaskTemplates < ActiveRecords::Base
  scope :offset_by_1, offset(1) 
end

# Controller
@project_task_templates = Product.other_queries.offset_by_1
```

Comment: Is TaskTemplate.where(:project_task_template_id => @project_task_template.id) an query object (so offset will work)?

Comment: @user938363, I can't validate the arguments but `where` is query object, or more precisely ActiveRecord::Relation object. All scopes adding limitation to SQL(where, order, limit, and many more) are this type of object: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Here is the one worked as well (.each removed): <%= f.fields_for :task_templates, TaskTemplate.where(:project_task_template_id => @project_task_template.id).offset(1) do |builder| %> 
    <p><%= render('task_templates', :f => builder) %></p> 
  <% end if @project_task_template.task_templates.size > 1 %>

Comment: @user938363, yes I know such things would work in view as well, but it's not good practice to put such logic in view. View should be dumb.

Comment: If offset is by default, scope in model is a way to go. I see what you mean. Thanks.